# выбрать правильный атрибут value из button jquery

Tags: jquery, button, выборка

Есть 3 кнопки

```
<button type="submit" onclick="send_comm(1)" class="mbutton" value="1" >One</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="send_comm(2)" class="mbutton" value="3">Two</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="send_comm(3)" class="mbutton" value="2">Three</button>
```

есть функция обработчик

```
function send_comm(e) {
        $.post("../comms", {'m': e, 'c': $(".mbutton").val() });
        return false;
    }
```

При нажатии на любую кнопку передает значение атрибута value в обработчик  только из первой кнопки. Подскажите как правильно использовать this что бы он передал именно значение атрибута где была нажата кнопка

Comment: Заменить `$(".mbutton").val()` на `$(this).val()`

Comment: @MedvedevDev `e`  это число

Comment: @teran, а, сорри, не вник в контекст xDD

Comment: появилась ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined видимо из-за того что this берет не тот обьект

Comment: это только для примера они одинаковые, на практике они будут разные в принципе  решил этот вопрос через send_comm(e,c) убрал value И сделал onclick="send_comm(3,2)". Но это костыль, хочется сделать более элегантно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".mbutton").on("click", function(){
   $.post("../comms", {'m': $(this).data("num"), 'c': $(this).val() });
   return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="mbutton" data-num="1" value="1" >One</button>
<button type="submit" class="mbutton" data-num="2" value="3">Two</button>
<button type="submit" class="mbutton" data-num="3" value="2">Three</button>
```

**UPD: смена текста кнопки**

```js
$(".mbutton").on("click", function() {
  var obj = $(this);
  $.post("../comms", {
      'm': obj.data("num"),
      'c': obj.val()
    })
    .done(function() {
      obj.text("Выключить модуль " + obj.data("num"));
    });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="mbutton" data-num="1" value="1">Включить модуль 1</button>
<button type="submit" class="mbutton" data-num="2" value="3">Включить модуль 2</button>
<button type="submit" class="mbutton" data-num="3" value="2">Включить модуль 3</button>
```

Comment: спасибо , вот это уже ближе к той реализации которую планировал изначально. Как сделать что бы после отправки запроса изменить название кнопки без перегрузки страницы?

Comment: @АлексейМануйлов возможно Вам и submit на кнопках ни к чему. в таком случае следует использовать `button type="button"` и убрать `return false;` как ненужный.

Comment: смысл какой допустим на кнопке надписать "Включить модуль" нажали на кнопку модуль выключился и поменялось название на "Выключить модуль"

Comment: @АлексейМануйлов  см.upd к ответу

Comment: спасибо! все получилось

Comment: @АлексейМануйлов если решение Вам помогло, ответьте ответ как решение. Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку слева от ответа. Галка станет [зелёной](http://prntscr.com/iw79bz). Это будет означать, что ответ отмечен как решение вопроса.